# SQL creating a join between two tables

Tags: sql-server

I want to create three tables.

1. Orders (contains an order ID and a customer name)
2. Products (contains a Product ID, description, and price)
3. Line Item (contains Order ID, Line Item ID, Product ID, and Quantity)

I want my web app to allow a customer to select an order number, and as a result, it will display the products that are in that order, the quantity of said products, the price of the products, and a total price of order that will be calculated on the fly in my code behind.

My SQL looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
ProductID int NOT NULL,
ProductDescription varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
ProductPrice smallmoney NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ProductID)
)

CREATE TABLE Orders(
OrderID int NOT NULL,
CustomerName varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (OrderID)
)

CREATE TABLE LineItem(
LineItemID int NOT NULL,
OrderID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Orders(OrderID),
ProductID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Products(ProductID),
Quantity int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (LineItemID)
)
```

Here is the database diagram with the relationships. 
[image: Database diagram]

Here is the result of a select all statement on all the tables

[image: database tables]

Are my relationships set up correctly for what I want to achieve? I'm sorry if this seems simple but I'm new to this and while the SQL Statements are pretty easy, the way to relate tables is not.

Comment: Yes your tables and relationships all look fine.

Comment: You need to store the item price at the time of the order to deal with price changes.

Comment: Your relations looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.ProductPrice, p.ProductDescription, o.CustomerName, l.Quantity 
FROM LineItem AS l 
INNER JOIN Products AS p ON l.ProductID=p.ProductID 
INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON l.OrderID=o.OrderID 
ORDER BY l.LineItemID
```

will provide combined information from all of these tables. You may add any additional columns which you want to fetch data from.

`INNER JOIN` and `JOIN` keywords are syntactic sugar, which have same effect. While you're binding two tables by `INNER JOIN`, only results which contained in both of these tables will be returned.

With the `ON` keyword, you are defining the relational columns of tables. For example, in the clause `INNER JOIN Products AS p ON l.ProductID=p.ProductID`, I'm defining that the data are relational in column `ProductID` of table `Products` with column `ProductID`  of table `LineItem`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I understand SELECT AND FROM but can you explain to me how the JOIN works in this? I've used INNER JOIN in my code behind but only by following other examples.

Comment: @onTheInternet I've added some further explanations. Please feel free to ask questions comes to your mind about `JOIN`s.

Comment: When i tried to run this, i got the error 'o.OrderID' could not be found. Im confused about this because p.ProductPrice works

Comment: @onTheInternet Sorry, my fault. Forgot to add alias `o` to table Orders. Now it shall work.

Comment: How can I expand this to also include the product description?

Comment: @onTheInternet Edited my answer to include the product description. `p` is an alias for table `Products`, `o` is for `Orders` and `l` is for `LineItem`. You may add any columns from any of these  tables as you desire to fetch data from.

Answer (score 1):

You have a **many-to-many** relationship between **Products** and **Orders** so in the structure of **LineItem** table I think you already have have the **primary key (Product Id,OrderID)** and I think you do not need to **LocalItemID**

```
CREATE TABLE LineItem(
 OrderID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Orders(OrderID),
 ProductID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Products(ProductID),
 Quantity int NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (OrderID ,ProductID )
)
```

and you can join the tables using this:

```
SELECT p.ProductPrice, o.CustomerName, li.Quantity 
 FROM LineItem AS li 
 JOIN Products AS p ON li.ProductID=p.ProductID 
 JOIN Orders ON li.OrderID=o.OrderID
```